# Analyzing Split-plot design

Tags: split-plot

Am new to R. Am teaching myself and I got stuck with a data I wish to analyze. The design is a split plot and I have the following variables:
Rep, Mainplot, Subplot, Weeks after Planting and measure values from SprntCnt1 - SprntCnt5.

My question is how do I arrange it in a code for ANOVA. I suppose if I get this I can be able to manipulate it however I want using other forms of analysis

[image]